# How "WPM" calculate in typing speed apps?

Tags: typing

I'm working on typing speed app and I need to know what's the Formula of calculating WPM (Words Per Minute)

Edit:
indeed i know:

```
wpm = correct_characters_in_60_seconds / 5
```

but i have no idea what should i do with decimal numbers like 22.6 or 19.7 and...

for example if user typed 158 keystrokes in 60 seconds so, `158/5 = 31.6`
so do the result should be 32 WPM or 31 WPM? How?
thanks.

Comment: `number_of_words_typed / elapsed_time_in_seconds * 60` ?

Comment: @PaulR no sir indeed i know: wpm = correct_characters_in_60_seconds / 5 but i have no idea what should i do with non-rounded numbers like 22.6 or 19.7 and...

Comment: There is no convention here. There's nothing about WPM that says it has to be an integer—if you're asking how to present it to your users, that's a question for what you want your users to see. "Just show the decimal" is just as good an answer as "round it down" or "round it to the nearest integer"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPM (Word per minute)

For the purpose of typing measurement, each word is standardized to be five characters or keystrokes long, including spaces and punctuation. For example, the phrase "I run" counts as one word, but "rhinoceros" and "let's talk" both count as two.

So the formula is:

```
Number_of_keystroke / time_in_minute * percentages_of_accurate_word
```

or

```
Number_of_keystroke / time_in_second * 60 * percentages_of_accurate_word
```

When dealing with decimals you should round down when the decimal is >.5 , else round down

Example:

5.5 -> 6

7.3 -> 7

3.49 -> 3

4.51 -> 5

Comment: sorry sir but this is not my answer. I have edited my question. please check it again.

Comment: what standard is this answer referencing? is this an official standard of some sort? is this used by any significant / notable bodies / applications?

Comment: @starball I assume they were referencing the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_per_minute) which references [1] [Analysis of Text Entry Performance Metrics (Ahmed Sabbir Arif, Wolfgang Stuerzlinger)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923174328/http://www.asarif.com/pub/papers/arif_ticsth09.pdf) which has further sources and info, in addition to the "five characters per word" claim.

Answer (score 0):

Words per minute(WPM) should be rounded off to the closest decimal value.

In your case 158/5 = 31.6 should be reported as 32 and not 31.

However if the the value was 156/5 = 31.2 then it should be rounded off to 31 to approximate the closest decimal value and hence averaging the overall error.

> if WPM<=x.5 then WPM = x else WPM = x+1